# How to tackle "duplicate" problem?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I wanted a post a problem which was very different from my own post [Multiple Choice question about a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281336/multiple-choice-question-about-a-continuous-function). But whenever I wanted to post it, it says that this question is an exact duplicate of the above problem (as given in the link). I even changed the title of the post but the problem persists. I can not even delete it (the previous post as given in the link) since it had answers in it. I am perplexed and do not know how to tackle it. Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Was the text you actually wrote the same, and accompanied only by an image showing the problem?  I guess you could try writing about what you tried to do to solve the problem, the context in which you encounter the problem, any other thoughts you have about the problem, and it will not trigger the duplicate autodetection.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks a lot sir.I will follow your advice.

Comment: Dear user53386, in standard English duplicity refers to deception, double-dealing, lie and hypocrisy! What you want to ask is *How to tackle the duplicate problem ?*  (Note that *duplicate* can function as  a noun, an adjective or a verb in English, that morphologically very flexible language.)

Comment: I apologize sir for my unintentional mistake.I have edited the title of my post.